# Are x86 assembly instructions REPE/REPZ and REPNE/REPNZ equal?

Tags: assembly, x86

Just a quick question:

Are **REPE** equal to **REPZ** and **REPNE** equal to **REPNZ**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes - they are synonyms

The [Intel manual](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/) volume 2B (`Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual
Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, N-Z`) says:

> The REPZ and REPNZ prefixes are
>   synonymous forms of the REPE and REPNE
>   prefixes, respectively.)

Comment: Thanks for such a concise and extremely objective answer. Just what I needed.